# Can't seem to get my nested loop printing properly

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple program that draws a rectangle of asterisks given two dimensions, width and height. here is the code

```
public class Rectangle {

private int width, height;

public Rectangle(){
System.out.println("A rectangle created: width = 10 and height = 25");
width = 10;
height = 25;
}

public Rectangle(int w, int h){
if (w > 0 && w < 30 && h > 0 && h < 30){
    width = w;
    height = h;
    System.out.println("Rectangle Created: Height = "+h+" and width = "+w);
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid values for rectangle, Values ,ust be positive                and less than 30");
}
}

public int getArea(){
return width * height;  
}

public void draw(){
for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
    for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
}
}
```

My rectangle test code is as follows

```
public class TestRectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
        r1.draw();

        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(15,5);
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle r2: "   +r2.getArea());
        r2.draw();
    }

    }
```

The result is one long column of asterisks instead of the hoped for Rectangle.

Can somebody please point to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`println` prints the argument, then a newline.

You need to use `print` inside the inner loop, and a `println` once for each outer loop.

```
public void draw(){
    for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
        for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
  for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
      System.out.print("*");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add linebreaks.

After your inner for loop you should add the following:

```
System.out.print("\n");
//alternatively just use println which does almost exactly the same
```

[prinln writes the current line.separator to the current Print Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29)

```
println("foo"); == print("foo"); println(); == print("foo"); print(line.separator);
```

while line.separator usually, but not always is "\n"

this makes your code look like that:

```
for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
    for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void draw(){
  for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
    for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're using println. Println prints "\n" at the end of each line, so each time you print a "*" you print a \n, and go to the next line.

Could you try this in draw function ? Just change println for print function, and make the

```
public void draw(){
for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
    for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: No problem, this things happen to all of us!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void draw(){
for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

`println()`, will create a new line after printing to console, so in your inner loop you should n't have println, rather use `print()` and after inner loop have a new line print

Answer (score 0):

Try this out it will work for you

After your inner loop you should add the following:

```
System.out.print("\n");
```

Specific to your code:

```
for(int rowCounter=0; rowCounter<height; rowCounter++){
   for(int colCounter=0; colCounter<width; colCounter++){
      System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.print("\n");
}
```